# Discord js bot: Cannot send DM to users with specific role

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I seem to be having serious trouble sending DM's to all users with a specific role.

Here is my bot code:

```
bot.on('message', async message => {
    members = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === "12345678998765").members.map(m => m.user.id);
    
    members.forEach(member_id => {
        
        sleep(5000).then(() => {
            message.users.fetch(member_id, false).then((user) => {
                user.send("some message");
             });
        });
       
    });
});
```

This code gives me the error:

> Cannot read properties of null (reading 'roles')

on this line:

> members = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id ===  ....

However that is not the issue. When I comment out the sleep command to send the message and output the member roles using:

```
members.forEach(member_id => {

        console.log(member_id)

        //sleep(5000).then(() => {
        //    bot.users.fetch(member_id, false).then((user) => {
        //        user.send("some message");
        //     });
        //});
       
    });
```

I get a list returned in the console of all the user ID's.. So it must be returning the roles.

How do I send a message to all users with a specific role ID ?? I want to be able to loop through them and put a wait in to reduce the API requests and spam trigger.

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but your code in both `forEach` loops is different. Also, you can't fetch `users` from `message` (in the first forEach).

Comment: What version of Discord.js do you have?

Answer (score 0):

To fix your first issue, `message.guild` will be `null` in DM. Make sure it isn't DM, or if it has to be, choose a guild with `client.guilds.cache.get("id")`.

```js
bot.on("message", async message => {
    let { guild } = message
    if (!guild) guild = bot.guilds.cache.get("id")
    //...
})
```

To fix your other issue, you can run [`GuildMember#send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=send) rather than getting the IDs and fetching the users

```js
bot.on("message", async message => {
    let { guild } = message
    if (!guild) guild = bot.guilds.cache.get("id")
    let members = guild.roles.cache.get("12345678998765").members 
    // I used .get here because it's getting by ID
    
    members.forEach(member => {
        sleep(5000).then(() => member.send("some message"));
    });
})
```

The above code will get all the [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember)s and loop through every one of them, "sleeping" for 5 seconds (if the sleep parameter is milliseconds) and send the member a DM

Comment: Also, even though you are using `sleep`, it may be considered API abuse. It would probably be better to make a private channel for people with only these roles